# Web: Creating window within window

Tags: html, wordpress, scroll

I am creating a Wordpress blog where I have a grid of over 1000 items I have the items wrapping down the page. I tried searching online but couldn't figure out how to get a "scroll view". I want it so there is almost window within a window. If you look at the image bellow only the black area would scroll not the entire page. So how do I achieve this mini window affect in my blog?

Comment: A div with style overflow:auto or overflow:scroll would do it

Comment: where's your problem code? the stuff you need help with.

Comment: Your "scroll view" is called "div with scrollbar"

Comment: http://www.mark-allen.net/notes/layout/frames/ is interesting (but old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `overflow: auto` for div which u want to have the scrollbar. In case you want it to have the scrollbar all the time use: `overflow:scroll`. You need to have fixed height if you want to use this parameter I guess.

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

**My demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cXvDc/9/

Answer (score 0):

you seem like you need

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 100%; height: 200px">content here</div>
```

this will create a 100% wide, 200px tall div that will scroll once the content within it becomes taller than 200px.